# How to match a word 'starting with... ' but not if quoted?

Tags: php, regex

I need to filter out text string if there is a word starting with 199
Actually i'm using

```
/199/
```

But this match also nnn199nnn

I tried

```
/\b199/
```

so it matches only string with one or more word starting with 199

I some very rare cases I need to workaround this filter, so i thinked to simply 'quote' or 'doublequote' the 199xxx to "crack" the regex.

But "199xxx" will be matched ... and also '199' ...

So my question is

**How to match a word starting with 199 but not if the word itself is double-quoted?**

EDIT:
I must match:

- 199324342342
- but not 34431994433
- but not ciao199dsadsa
- **and not "1994553"** (because double quoted)

Comment: Realtebo.. do you want to mach `abc199`  or not ? and space before 199 ?

Comment: I written a Python code for you. May be you find [it helpful at **Codepad**](http://codepad.org/VjFgBcHH)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Why are you linking to Codepad instead of posting your answer here? It still has the same problems, though - the regex still matches `nnn199` or `"199"` or `'199'`, but you're using it wrong (`.matches()` anchors the search to the start of the string which is not desired here). For example, it would fail as soon as one non-word/non-space character occurs before `199` like in `Test! Match 199`...

Comment: @TimPietzcker I was not sure that my answer is correct, that is the reason I didn't post. Any ways Thanks your the feedback..

Comment: I nedd to match only words starting with 199. Bu if the word is doublequote, then word musts not be matched

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
/(?<!['"])\b199/
```

`(?<!['"])` checks that the character before the current position (which is right before the start of the number `199`) is neither a `'` nor a `"`.

Comment: @realtebo: Well, good news - then this regex will work. Hint: Don't put the language in the title, that's what the tags are for. You know, DRY principle and all that.